Intermittent "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated" errors
I'm moving my websites to a new VPS server. This includes some worker services that run in the background, and need to send emails.
I'm now getting intermittent errors.

SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: Authentication required

Now, given the error, the easy answer might be a wrong password or something like that. But it doesn't fail all the time. I left it running to send an email every hour last night. It failed 5 times. It succeeded 7 times.
I have no idea how to try and resolve this. Does anyone else have any ideas what I could try?
Note: Because the issue is intermittent, it doesn't seem like the code is important. But in case someone is wondering about the code, it looks like this.
try
{
    settings.LogFile.LogInfo("Sending email...");

    // Send email
    using SmtpClient client = new()
    {
        Host = settings.EmailSettings.Host,
        Port = settings.EmailSettings.Port,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(settings.EmailSettings.UserName, settings.EmailSettings.Password),
        EnableSsl = settings.EmailSettings.EnableSsl
    };

    using MailMessage message = new()
    {
        From = new MailAddress(settings.EmailSettings.FromAddress, settings.EmailSettings.FromName),
        Subject = "Test Message",
        Body = settings.EmailSettings.FormatMessage(),
        IsBodyHtml = false,
    };

    // Add recipients
    foreach (string recipient in settings.EmailSettings.Recipients.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        message.To.Add(recipient);
    }

    // Send email
    client.Send(message);
    settings.LogFile.LogInfo("Email Sent.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    settings.LogFile.LogError(ex);
}


If you are using the .Net mail client, I believe it is deprecated or not recommended for new projects. I believe I was having a similar problem to yours and I replaced it with the MailKit nuget package.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-8.0 "The SmtpClient type is obsolete on some platforms and not recommended on others; for more information, see the Remarks section."

@B.O.B.: Thanks. I hadn't heard this before. Looking into it...
